# Using JNI to create a DLL that can be shared between my Java and C++ programs

Tags: java, c++

So I created both of my files (one for C++ on for Java). Went through all the steps listed here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html and everything went alright. I have the header file and I have the DLL. But when I try to run my Java file I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\Project2\p2_IO.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at p2.main(p2.java:17)
```

I checked using java -version and it says that I have a 64-bit version.

I used the following to build the DLL:

```
cl -Ic:\jdk\include -Ic:\jdk\include\win32 -LD p2_IO.cpp -p2_IO.dll
```

I notice that I am using win32 directory. But the thing is, I don't see any win64. What gives? Could someone please explain where the error in the mismatch is? I'm not sure if I need to modify my C++ side or my Java side. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would trust the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` message. You are trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit JVM. Which side do you want to fix? Compile as a 64-bit DLL or switch to a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: Regarding the `win32` directory, I see that Oracle's JDK names it that way on Windows, regardless of whether the JDK/JVM is 32-bit or 64-bit. So this is not a point to worry about

Comment: @Nayuki So my command line check of java -version might be lying? I have no preference of which one to change... I guess whichever one would be simplest and fastest :)

Comment: Well do you have another JVM installed which is 32-bit? If you do, this would be the faster solution

Comment: @Nayuki Not at the moment. It wouldn't be a problem for my to install it though. Only hesitation, I am running at 64-bit OS. Will this be an issue?

Comment: Windows x64 can always run old 32-bit executables.

Comment: @Nayuki Could you provide a link by any chance? I tried searching Oracle and the only options I can see are for 64 bit and 86 bit. Link for reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: @aurora91 x86 is the 32-bit version.

Comment: @Casey Oh... that's pretty weird. I'll try that out then.